# $y^2 = x^3 - 26$, exist ideal satisfying conditions?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, ring-theory, algebraic-number-theory

For the solution $(x, y) = (3, 1)$ of $y^2 = x^3 - 26$,

> does there necessarily exist an ideal $I$ of the integer ring $\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-26}]$ of $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-26})$ such that $(y + \sqrt{-26}) = (1 + \sqrt{-26})$ is equal to $I^3$ but this $I$ is not principal?

Comment: a method that works at http://math.blogoverflow.com/2014/08/23/binary-quadratic-forms-over-the-rational-integers-and-class-numbers-of-quadratic-%EF%AC%81elds/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let $K=\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-26})$, and $\sigma$ its non-trivial automorphism. We have ${\cal O}_K=\mathbb{Z}[\sqrt{-26}].$

If $I^3 = (1+\sqrt{-26})$, then 
$$N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(I)^3=(I I^\sigma)^3 = I^3 (I^\sigma)^3 = (1+\sqrt{-26})(1-\sqrt{-26})=(27)=(3)^3.$$
Then $I I^\sigma=N_{K/\mathbb{Q}}(I)=(3)$. Since $3$ is prime, $I$ (and $I^\sigma$) must be prime ideals.

So you're asking whether 3 splits in $K$, and if so, whether the prime ideal dividing $3$ is non-principal. The answer is yes, and
$$I = (3,1+\sqrt{-26}).$$

It's not hard to see that $II^\sigma \subset (3)$, and $(3)\subset II^\sigma$ follows from

$$ 3 = 3^2-3(1+\sqrt{-26})-3(1-\sqrt{-26}).$$

Then $3=II^\sigma$ and $I$, $I^\sigma$ are prime ideals. Also $I\neq I^\sigma$ since $3$ does not divide $26$.

The prime decomposition of $(1+\sqrt{-26})(1-\sqrt{-26})=(27)$ is $I^3 (I^\sigma)^3$, so the possible prime factors of $(1+\sqrt{-26})$ are $I$ and $I^\sigma$. Since $II^\sigma = (3)$ and $(3)$ does not divide $(1+\sqrt{-26})$, either $(1+\sqrt{-26})=I^3$ or $(I^\sigma)^3$. Since $1+\sqrt{-26}\in I$, $I$ already divides $(1+\sqrt{-26})$, so $(1+\sqrt{-26})=I^3$.

Comment: By "its non-trivial automorphism" do you mean the conjugation, right?

Comment: Yes, if we pick an embedding $K\subset \mathbb{C}$ it corresponds to complex conjugation.

Comment: One more question: the answer seems to use the solution of the given equation $x=3$. Is there a general conclusion that a solution $(x_0,y_0)$ of an equation similar to the one used by the OP (say $x^2=y^3-d$ with $d$ square-free and $d\equiv 2,3\bmod 4$) gives rise to a nontrivial ideal $I=(x_0,y_0+\sqrt{d})$ in the class group (when the class group is not trivial, of course)?

Comment: This fails for $d=39$ and $(x_0,y_0)=(4,5)$. Then $\mathbb{Q}(\sqrt{-39})$ has class number 4, and $(5+\sqrt{-39})=(2,\frac{\sqrt{-39}}{2}-\frac{1}{2})(2,\frac{\sqrt{-39}}{2}+1/2)^5$.

Comment: Other counter-example triples $(x_0,y_0,d)$ are $(4,7,15)$, $(6,13,47)$, and $(8,21,71)$.